# How to change the mapping for a map in Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, hibernate-mapping

The default mapping for a Map in Grails 2.0.0 only allows strings of less than 255 characters in the value field and I need more.

I could obviously change my Maps to a user-defined hasMany of key/value entities but I am porting a large project from 1.3.7 which has a lot of Maps and would like to solve the issue with one change.

I have read in two other StackOverflow questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301427/specifying-field-size-of-map-collection-in-grails-dom) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237393/how-to-adjust-constraints-db-mapping-for-map-within-grails-domain-class)) that to change this I need to "involve a custom handler for Hibernate for the HashMap type", but where and how exactly do I do this?

I have found nothing in the standard Grails docs.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried applying a global database mapping? http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/ref/Database%20Mapping/Usage.html

Comment: I would like to, but this one example you have pointed to, which crops up everywhere, does not really give me enough to go on. I confess that I hoped to just find a cut'n'pasteable code snippet so I could get away with not having to penetrate the gloomy depths of hibernate. That may be my biggest "problem".

Comment: I would like to try but this example gives me no clue how I would do it for the predefined Map type.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to cope with a custom `UserType`, as it's done in the [Joda-Time plugin](https://github.com/gpc/grails-joda-time) to handle Joda-Time types the same as Gorm types

You'll find an other example [there](http://omaha-seattle.blogspot.com/2010/02/grails-hibernate-custom-data-type.html)